OutputPath property not set for 'VCTargetsPath.vcxproj'
I try to build the OsmAnd native rendering library following this guide: Compile Native rendering library for OsmAndMapCreator.
However, I get an error in step #3 of the guide, when I execute amd64-windows-vc12.cmd. That's the complete message:
 Project "D:\Documents\02 Projekte\OsmAnd ORM\DevEnvironment\core-legacy\targets\amd64-windows-vc12.baked\CMakeFiles\3.29.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(839,5): error : The BaseOutputPath/OutputPath property is not set for project 'VCTargetsPath.vcxproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Debug'  Platform='x64'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [D:\Documents\02 Projekte\OsmAnd ORM\DevEnvironment\core-legacy\targets\amd64-windows-vc12.baked\CMakeFiles\3.29.3\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]


As the vctargetspath.vcxproj is automatically created during the build process, the actual problem must be located some step earlier.
I can't figure out why the build configuration won't fit. Is it an issue of my system setup?

CMake v3.29.3 Win x64 edition
Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition
.NET SDK 8.0.300 x64 edition
Win10 Pro on an intel-i5 x64 machine


The CMake command is using -G "Visual Studio 12 Win64" but Visual Studio 2022 is Visual Studio 17, i.e. try using -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64.

With -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64 I get:
  Generator
    Visual Studio 17 2022
  could not find any instance of Visual Studio.```

Ah, that pointed me on the right problem. See my answer below (I'll mark it as solution as soon as I'm allowed to).
Thanks!

It really was the version issue of visual studio named in the comment;
-G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64
returned:
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
   Generator     Visual Studio 17 2022   
could not find any instance of Visual Studio.

which could be resolved by adding the "Desktop development with C++" to Visual Studio, as described in this tip here: CMake: Visual Studio 15 2017 could not find any instance of Visual Studio.

On a host for a build agent the "Build Tools for Visual Studio" can be used which is essentially Visual Studio without the GUI IDE. Build Tools uses the same "Visual Studio Installer" as the other Visual Studio editions.

The Visual Studio Installer can create a .vsconfig file - see "Import or export installation configurations". Install the C++ workload and any other required components, export the configuration to a .vsconfig file, save the .vsconfig file to the directory that contains your .sln solution file, and commit the .vsconfig to version control. On a new machine when the solution is opened, Visual Studio will use the .vsconfig to show that required components need to be installed.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. Can you [edit] your answer to summarize the relevant guidance from the link? Answers on Stack Overflow can certainly link to additional information, but they should stand on their own even if the page they are linking to is later (re)moved. This is important because often, over time, the linked pages are no longer available, which is frustrating for future members of the community.
